# Bizarro Swing JList Model Behavior

Tags: swing, model, jlist

I am having an issue in my Swing app where I am creating a simple JList by passing it a model - and even though the model is demonstrably populated, the JList refuses to display it's own model's contents.

```
DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
String[] modelElems = {"Apple", "Orange", "Banana"};
for(int i = 0; i < modelElems.length; i++)
    dlm.add(i, modelElems[i]);

JList lstFruitList = new JList(dlm);
lstFruitList.setVisible(true);
```

When my Swing app runs, I see the JList on screen, but it is completely empty!  I've looked at countless examples, poured over the Swing tutorials, and cannot seem to figure out what is going on.  Anybody ever had this happen to them before?!? Anything that is glaringly-obviously-wrong?!?

**NOTE:**

The following print statement indeed shows that my model has 3 elements:

```
// Prints "Fruit List model has a size of 3"
System.out.println("Fruit List model has a size of " + dlm.size());
```

**However**, if I try to loop through and print the names of the fruits in my model, by calling `(String)dlm.get(i)` at every iteration (where `i` is the iteration var), it prints each model element as `null`...

hmmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code works fine for me. Some thoughts:

- I see that you call the `setVisible` on the JList, how exactly are you adding it to whatever you are displaying?
- Are you adding the elements *after* you display your JFrame?  If I remember correctly, that won't work well, I think you have to repaint everything.
- Make sure that you're not messing around with the list model at some point; Maybe at some point later in the code, you're changing it?
- Ensure that you are actually looking at the right element; maybe your list is hidden behind something else?(try setting the background color, i.e. `lstFruitList.setBackground(Color.BLUE);`
- Final thought, are you sure that you've compiled it properly?  I've sometimes accidentally forgotten to compile, or had messed up something and was running an older version of the code and was confused as to why something didn't work.

For reference, here's the code that I ran:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class javatest{

    public static void main(String[] args){
            JFrame f = new JFrame("HELLO");
            DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
            String[] modelElems = {"Apple", "Orange", "Banana"};
            for(int i = 0; i < modelElems.length; i++)
                dlm.add(i, modelElems[i]);

            JList lstFruitList = new JList(dlm);
            lstFruitList.setVisible(true);

            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.add( lstFruitList );
            f.add( p );
            f.setLocation(0,0);
            f.setSize(400,400);
            f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response @rm5248 - a few things. (1) Yes it absolutely compiles fine; I'm using NB 7.0 for my IDE and I have zero build errors. (2) Yes, setting the background colors works, so I know I am looking at the right component! (3) I'm actually laying the GUI out in the NB GUI builder, which I am now suspecting is the root problem.  (4) Why is it problematic to modify (add elements to, remove them from) the model after setting it in the `JList` constructor?  That doesn't sound very dynamic, especially for Java!  What do you think about the GUI builder?

Comment: Also, the NB GUI builder autogenerates immutable code (cannot be edited from inside NB anyways). If I use the GUI builder to set the JList's model to those three fruit values, I see it add an anonymous AbstractModel subclass in the autogenerated JList constructor. This seems to work. Using the *same exact* code on my own fails to work!  Code their be some kind of "pane" (not really comfortable with my understanding of root panes, glass panes, etc.) over my JList that is blocking me from seeing the model?

Comment: So this code works....can anybody answer why???         AbstractListModel dlm = new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Pear" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        };
        
        lstAvailablePlans.setModel(dlm);